# Reports API: User Usage – Gmail Parameters

Tags: google-admin-sdk

what does last_interaction_time and last_access_time in reports api mean? I want to get the date of any last activity on the gmail account.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail

```
gmail:last_interaction_time

gmail:last_access_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Per a recent ticket I had with Google:

- gmail:last_access_time: when the account was last accessed.
- gmail:last_interaction_time: when the last interaction (mail sent or received) occurred.